# Dynamic font (Downloading) in run time for Xamarin Forms dev

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm in Need to use custom font in app i.e downloadable/cachable  at run time in storage/cache memory instead of packaged within app ( Resource/assets).

Need help on using custom font downloadable at run time approach in Xamarin forms (for Android & iOS platforms) .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Instead of packaging fonts as an application resource, Android can download fonts from a remote source. You could refer to the MS docs about how to download the fonts. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/fonts#downloading-fonts

Comment: Ok, but for iOS ,do have any option like for android?

Comment: I found something useful. You could check the two links below about download and install fonts dynamically to iOS app. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16792235/11850033   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36376829/how-can-i-download-and-install-fonts-dynamically-to-ios-app/36377440#36377440