# Ensure SkiaSharp font and Xamarin Forms default font match

Tags: xamarin.forms, fonts, skiasharp

I'm using SkiaSharp in Xamarin Forms. My goal is to ensure that the font displayed in Xamarin controls, e.g. a Label, matches the font used in SkiaSharp drawing.

In addition, I want to use the default font so that the app looks right on its respective platform and adheres to user preferences.

In my simple app, I have some Xamarin labels and I have a custom control drawn by SkiaSharp. The two have different fonts, though they are very close. SkiaSharp has the same look but is about 10% smaller. And Xamarin has wider antialiasing.

See clip of screenshot (top: SkiaSharp, bottom: Xamarin):

[image: top:SkiaSharp, bottom:Xamarin]

I'm not sure how to solve this. There are at least a couple approaches:

1. How can I determine the font being used for a Xamarin Label ? If I can determine this, I should be able to set it for SkiaSharp drawing.
2. Or, how do I set the Xamarin font to that being used by SkiaSharp. I can get the font family from SkiaSharp during runtime but I don't know how to set it in Xamarin during runtime.

I guess a third alternative is to do all fonts via SkiaSharp. But then I won't be able to use any Xamarin controls that display text.

Comment: Hi, about modify font on runtime, you could have a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60784139/dynamic-font-downloading-in-run-time-for-xamarin-forms-dev), it may be helpful.

Comment: I'm hoping there's a Xamarin solution. That link has a solution for Android and a separate solution for iOS. No solution for UWP (though I'm sure there is one). Further, they are not written using Xamarin Forms, and may use completely different APIs.

Comment: Suggestion, try saving your screenshot as a PNG; JPEG compression might be messing with things.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the **SkiaSharp** use the default system text font to draw text.

If you could set the `TextSize` to fit the default `FontSize`, you will see they will show the same.

Have a look at this screenshot:

[image]

The one above is `Label` and the one below is `SKCanvasView` in **Xaml**:

```
<Label Text="Hello SkiaSharp!" x:Name="mylabel" VerticalOptions="Start" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
<forms:SKCanvasView PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface" />
```

The `OnCanvasViewPaintSurface` method is:

```
void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
{
    SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
    SKSurface surface = args.Surface;
    SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

    canvas.Clear();

    string str = "Hello SkiaSharp!";

    // Create an SKPaint object to display the text
    SKPaint textPaint = new SKPaint
    {
        Color = SKColors.Chocolate
    };

    // Adjust TextSize property so text is 90% of screen width
    float textWidth = textPaint.MeasureText(str);
    //textPaint.TextSize = 0.9f * info.Width * textPaint.TextSize / textWidth;
    textPaint.TextSize = (float)((float)mylabel.FontSize*(2.6));

    //textPaint.Typeface = SKTypeface.FromFamilyName("monospace");

    // Find the text bounds
    SKRect textBounds = new SKRect();
    textPaint.MeasureText(str, ref textBounds);

    // Calculate offsets to center the text on the screen
    float xText = info.Width / 2 - textBounds.MidX;
    float yText = info.Height / 2 - textBounds.MidY;

    // And draw the text
    canvas.DrawText(str, xText, yText, textPaint);

    // Create a new SKRect object for the frame around the text
    SKRect frameRect = textBounds;
    frameRect.Offset(xText, yText);
    frameRect.Inflate(10, 10);

    // Create an SKPaint object to display the frame
    SKPaint framePaint = new SKPaint
    {
        Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
        StrokeWidth = 5,
        Color = SKColors.Blue
    };

    // Draw one frame
    canvas.DrawRoundRect(frameRect, 20, 20, framePaint);

    // Inflate the frameRect and draw another
    frameRect.Inflate(10, 10);
    framePaint.Color = SKColors.DarkBlue;
    canvas.DrawRoundRect(frameRect, 30, 30, framePaint);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What you claim is that the default fonts should be the same. In your example, they do appear to be the same. In my case, even if I adjust the size, they are not the same.

Comment: @PeriHartman Hi, they are the same `Font`. From shared image, it seems their sizes of `Text` are not the same. But `Font` is the same. If you set `monospace` for the `FamilyFont` of `Lable`(one of Android system fonts), and add code `textPaint.Typeface = SKTypeface.FromFamilyName("monospace");` in `OnCanvasViewPaintSurface` method. You could check that whether it works in your project.

Comment: Ok, I'll take your word for it. The problem, then, must be in the rendering. Different antialiasing algorithms, perhaps. Thanks.